# The operator '[]'

Tags: dart, operator-keyword, void

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) async {
    var body = await req.parseBody();

    var name = body['name'];
    var email = body['email'];
    var phone = body['phone'];
    var pass = body['pass'];
    var image = body['image'];
  });
```

[image]

21:21: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'void'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using [Angel](https://docs.angel-dart.dev/v/2.x/guides/body-parsing), so try this:

```dart
await req.parseBody();

var name = req.bodyAsMap['name'];
```

Comment: Angel? Is this the one that is dead?